# UITableviewcell show delete button from using dictionary keys instead of NSMutableArray array data

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, dictionary

This is my code for delete the row in tableviewcell.

```
  - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
        if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
          [Keys removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];  // this line error
            [_tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSMutableArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
        }
}
```

the error line is `[Keys removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];' .

I know this code should be use in NSMutableArray, but i want use this same method for Dictionary Keys from  Plist for delete the cell.

the editable:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    CustomeCell *Customecell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (Customecell == nil){
        Customecell =[[CustomeCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }
    Customecell.nameLbl.text = [Keys objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    Customecell.Img.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[[content valueForKey:[Keys objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]] valueForKey:@"image"]];
    Customecell.statusLabel.text = [[content valueForKey:[Keys objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]] valueForKey:@"status"];
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm"];

    // NSString *dateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];  // current date
    NSString *dateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:[[content valueForKey:[Keys objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]] valueForKey:@"date"]];
    NSLog(@"date: %@", dateString);
    Customecell.dateLbl.text=dateString;
    return Customecell;
```

Comment: please any know the answer let me know.

Comment: What's your code in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`? If we don't know how your `NSDictionary` objects serves as a model datasource, we can't help you.

Comment: the error is : No visible @interface for 'NSArray' declares the selector 'removeObjectAtIndex:'

Comment: I don't understand. You are talking about `NSDictionary`, but apparently `Keys` is a `NSArray`? If you want to delete items, `Keys` should be a `NSMutableArray`. So, where you create it, make it mutable, what's your code when you initialize it ?

Comment: Larme my code in tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath is, please see above i edited and added.

Comment: its converted NSDictionary to NSArray.

Comment: Where is defined `Keys`? Show how it's initialized. Plus, you shouldn't name you var starting with an uppercase.

Comment: My problem is how to delete the row using dictionary Keys from Plist doc.

Comment: NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Property List" ofType:@"plist"];
    content = [[NSDictionary alloc]initWithContentsOfFile:path];
    NSLog(@"%@", content);
    Keys=[content allKeys];

Comment: Declare `Keys` as a mutable dictionary, and do `Keys = [[content allKeys] mutableCopy]; `

Comment: @interface ViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource,LGChatControllerDelegate>{
    NSDictionary *content;
    NSArray *Keys;
}

Comment: =>`{ NSDictionary *content; NSMutableArray *Keys; }` and `Keys = [[content allKeys] mutableCopy];`.

Comment: Larme i changed like your code there is no error but the button not showing in tableview.

Answer (score 0):

Try This Code

```
      - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
        {
            if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
                [_tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[Keys objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
                [Keys removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];  // this line error
            }
    }
```